# Different fieldset view problem between firefox and internet explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, html, legend, fieldset

I am designing a page with divs in fieldset to create an effect like the page in url below. I can not insert the screenshot. Look  at the left coloumn of fieldset boxes. If you surf the page with firefox, you will se the view that i want it to be. But in Internet Explorer 9 view, the paddings are gone and the legend backgrounds are leaked to outside? I need your help. Thank you to all.

url » http://www.cagetur.com/yeni

### TRUE - Firefox 4:

http://www.cagetur.com/yeni/ff.jpg

### FALSE - Internet Explorer:

http://www.cagetur.com/yeni/ie.jpg

Comment: Add a link to the screenshot, and it will be edited into your question for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good strings to search Google with include:

- ie fieldset background fix
- ie fieldset background color bleed bug

These results look good:

- http://www.communitymx.com/content/article.cfm?page=1&cid=DD9F3
- http://www.gunlaug.no/tos/moa_18a.html

If you need more precise instructions for your situation, let me know and I will spend some time trying these fixes with your actual page.

Comment: I tried the instructions in both pages. Unfortunately i cant succeeded it. Firefox still good. IE still bad. I will be glad if you have time to look at my page. Thank you.